# Мощности для обучения нейронной сети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Есть нейронная сеть с объёмом обучающих данных в размере 1.5 миллионов записей и размером словаря в 20.000 тысяч слов. Для того объёма нужно сотни гигабайт оперативной памяти. Есть ли сервисы предоставляющее подобные мощности за относительно небольшие деньги?

Comment: Откуда она есть, если у вас логически не хватает памяти? как вы поняли. что там 1.5 миллиона записей? Нестыковочки.

Comment: каждая запись это 1 строка в текстовом файле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотрите в сторону [colab.research](https://colab.research.google.com) ([статья на хабре](https://habr.com/post/348058/))

из плюсов:

- неплохие вычислительные мощности
- бесплатно

из минусов - есть ограничения (при желании обходятся)

Микрософт тоже дает халявные ~ 10 000 (виртуальных) рублей/мес, которые можно использовать чтобы подснять вычислительные мощности.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то обучающие данные, поступающие на вход нейронной сети и объем памяти, необходимый для представления нейронной сети - это как бы разные вещи. Ну, хотя-бы потому, что данные можно подавать на вход нейронки для обучения последовательно, пример за примером, в не всем скопом.  Так что ваши полтора миллиона записей вполне могут быть обработаны на каких нибудь 16 или 32 ГБ оперативки.

P.S. Или вы перепутали нейронную сеть и "жадный алгоритм классификации" типа k-NN?
Так и в последнем даже случае влезть в десяток гигабайт с вашими данными - в общем-то не проблема.